# JavaScript and array of strings containing \r and / or \n characters

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, newline, carriage-return

I have a dynamically generated array from a database. Basically it's an array of objects which PHP prints out to the page in the  section.

The final output is somrthing like:
`var arPersons=[{'name':'aaa',description:'2-3 lines text in 300px wide div'},{etc}];`

Now there seems to be a problem with this array when newline caracters (`\n`) or carriage return characters (`\r`) appear in the description text as that is written from a CMS.

How can I solve this?
What I currently do is `str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),"",$description);`, where $description is changed for each element in the loop.

I am unsure this is the best way. Is there a way I can tell the JS code not to mess up when there are \n and \r characters somehow? Should it still be done in PHP rather than JS?

**EDIT:**
By `mess up` I mean any code after that array stops being executed. If I remove description entirely or just the \n and \r characters it will work (in both cases).

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "mess up"?  What goes wrong?  There's nothing inherently illegal or improper about newline or carriage return characters.

Comment: It breaks any JS code after that part. if I remove the new line characters it works. I am also using jQuery on the page if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to use `json_encode()` from the start.  It fully escapes everything for output to Javascript.

http://php.net/json-encode

Comment: Hmm, clever. I hope it doesn't affect HTML in the description property as it need it to have HTML. I'll give it a try and comeback. Thanks

Comment: @Francisc no, it won't break the HTML.  All it does is provide quoting as necessary to preserve JSON syntax, so HTML markup will be completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a nl2br() function that takes newlines in a string and turns them into `<br />`s. You could run your string through that if you are wanting to keep the formatting. The sub-par docs for nl2br are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: The OP wants to output to Javascript.  `nl2br` would not help; that's for HTML.

Comment: Seems like stackoverflow parsed something in your answer: "... and turns them into s"

Comment: I tried nl2br before the str_replace and it didn't work for some strange reason.